# Google Maps v3 Direction Renderer redraw response

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

Can I save the response from Google Maps API Direction Services in db as JSON and reuse that to draw on the map using google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();

I am already saving it in DB, but when I like to redraw on map using new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer(); it does not show line on Map. However it does display the direction panel based on my loaded JSON from db.

Below is code snippet:

```
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: 'controller.php',
                data: {action: 'routedata', id: id},
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function(data){
                    if(data && data.routes && data.routes.length > 0){
                        var thisRouteDirRender = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
                        thisRouteDirRender.setMap(map);
                        thisRouteDirRender.setPanel(document.getElementById('directions-panel'));
                        thisRouteDirRender.setDirections(data);
                    }
                }
            });
```

Comment: What does the saved data look like?

Answer (score 1):

I'm think you can try somethink like this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: 'controller.php',
    data: {action: 'routedata', id: id},
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data){
        if(data && data.routes && data.routes.length > 0){
            var thisRouteDirRender = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
            var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
            thisRouteDirRender.setMap(map);
            thisRouteDirRender.setPanel(document.getElementById('directions-panel'));
            var request = {
                origin: data.routes[0].LatLng ,
                destination: data.routes[data.routes.length - 1].LatLng,
                travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.WALKING
            };
            directionsService.route(request, function(result, status) {
                if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
                    thisRouteDirRender.setDirections(result);
                }
            });
        }
    }
});
```

You need use `google.maps.DirectionsService` to build route.
Also you can specify `waypoints[]` from `data`.
All additional parameters for request method you can see in [google docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions)

Comment: I was wondering that i cannot reuse the "result" JSON which Google API returned me initially? I am actually saving that JSON in database on initial call which is not shown in the code. The web site will let user to draw directions and save them and then redraw it using result JSON.

Comment: You can try store only coordinates and redraw directions with stored coordinates

Comment: @jonijones This takes lot of time, if the map data is large. I explored maps.data.addGeoJson() api but it is not drawing anything.